# How to model recursive structure in Dart

Tags: dart

I am having problems with modelling a structure where a `Node` has a child of a type `Child` that extends `Node`. Please look at the following simplified problem.

```
abstract class Node<Child extends Node<dynamic>> {
  Node(this.child);
  final Child child;
}

class FooNode extends Node<BarNode> {
  FooNode() : super(BarNode());
}

class BarNode extends Node {
  BarNode() : super(null);
}

void recurse(Node node) {
  final child = node.child;
  recurse(child);  // <--- FAILS
}
```

At `recurse(child)`, the compilation fails with

```
The argument type 'Node<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Node<Node<dynamic>>'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This in dartpad compiles just fine

Comment: Did you enable strict mode?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have either the no_implicit_downcast lint enabled, or you are using the null safe Dart experiment. In either case, assigning `Node<dynamic>` to `Node<Node<dynamic>>` is an implicit downcast, which is not allowed.

The type `Node<Node<dynamic>>` is a super-bounded type. It's what you get when you write just `Node`, because there is no finite type which satisfies `Child extends Node<Child>`.
Inference will decorate your code to:

```dart
void recurse(Node<Node<dynamic>> node) {
  final Node<dynamic> child = node.child;
  recurse(child);  // <--- FAILS
}
```

which is what causes your failure.

What you can do is to explicitly change the `recurse` function into:

```dart
void recurse(Node<dynamic> node) {
  final child = node.child as Node<dynamic>;
  recurse(child);
}
```